# autofilling a dict python 2.x

Tags: python-2.7

I'm quite new to Python and programming in general, so apologies if this is quite basic or has been asked and answered before. Here is a sample of the data I'm working with:

```
    {
    "homeTeam": {
     "formation": [
      "4",
      "4",
      "2"
    ],
    "lineupsSorted": [
      {
    "player": {
      "name": "Scott P. Brown",
      "slug": "scott-p-brown",
      "shortName": "S. P. Brown",
      "id": 19889,
      "hasImage": true
    },
    "position": 1,
    "shirtNumber": 1,
    "substitute": false,
    "positionName": "Goalkeeper",
    "positionNameshort": "G",
    "captain": false
  },
  {
    "player": {
      "name": "Carl Winchester",
      "slug": "carl-winchester",
      "shortName": "C. Winchester",
      "id": 110785,
      "hasImage": true
    },
    "position": 2,
    "shirtNumber": 27,
    "substitute": false,
    "positionName": "Midfielder",
    "positionNameshort": "M",
    "captain": false
  },
```

I am looking to automate populating defined names as I have done manually here:

```
    hometeamPositions =['Goalkeeper','Midfielder','Defender','Defender','Defender','Midfielder','Midfielder','Midfielder','Midfielder','Forward','Forward','Goalkeeper','Defender','Defender','Midfielder','Midfielder','Forward','Forward']

    hometeamPlayers = ['S. P. Brown','C. Winchester','M. Onariase','W. 
    Boyle','J. Cranston','H. Pell','J. Rowe','K. Storer','B. Waters','D. 
    Wright','D. Holman','R. Lovett','J. Barthram','T. Plavotic','J. 
    Munns','L. Davis','K. Wootton','J. Dayton']
```

As I will be repeating this process many hundreds of times with different data (same structure) I was wondering if anyone could give me some tips on automatically building these ranges?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what is the problem you are trying to solve but I'll try to help.

Assuming you have a dictionary `team_dict` and you want to create 2 list: `hometeamPositions` and `hometeamPlayers` you can use the following code:

```
hometeamPlayers = []
hometeamPositions = []

for player_dict in teams_dict['homeTeam']['lineupsSorted']:
    hometeamPlayers.append(player_dict['player']['shortName'])
    hometeamPositions.append(player_dict['positionName'])
```

The output on your example will be:

```
hometeamPlayers = ['S. P. Brown', 'C. Winchester']
hometeamPositions = ['Goalkeeper', 'Midfielder']
```